# FreeMarker recursive nested lists

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public Bar bar;
    public List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Each instance of Foo can hold an arbitrary amount of `Foo`S, which of course in turn can contain even more `Foo`S and so on. So how would I go about making FreeMarker go through a list like that ?

Comment: what do you need to do? print all Foo?

Comment: Sure, that's fine. I do need to retain order, depth, and branch history (as in, if i have a, a.b, a.c and a.b.d, I need to retain the information that d is a child of b, not c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FreeMarker macros (and functions) support recursion. So something like this:

```
<#macro dumpFoo foo>
  ${foo.bar}
  <#list foo.foos as childFoo>
    <@dumpFoo childFoo />
  </#list>
</#macro>

<@dumpFoo myFoo />
```

Example data-model (using https://try.freemarker.apache.org/ syntax, but it works equally well with `List`-s and `Foo` beans):

```
myFoo = {
  "bar": "root",
  "foos": [
    {
      "bar": "child 1",
      "foos": [
        {
          "bar": "child 1.1",
          "foos": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "bar": "child 2",
      "foos": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
  root
  child 1
  child 1.1
  child 2
```

Comment: This functionality is exactly what I had in mind, thank you! I got distracted from finding it on my own because searching for Freemarker lists and recursion leads down the XML path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use static methods to freemarker.

Add static method to Foo class printMe or doSomething

```
add public static printMe() { ...
}
```

This function will print itself and print it list as you need.

Now just call it from freemarker template

```
${statics["packageName.Foo"].printMe()}
```

see [Accessing static methods](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html#autoid_60)

Comment: That is really just circumventing Freemarker completely though, it wouldn't allow me to take advantage of large parts of the language.